# How to load OneToMany data when i set FetchType.LAZY

Tags: hibernate

I set @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY).but sometimes i want to load the data to use.
I use Hibernate4

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a lazy loaded collection will load the elements

Comment: Might want to add that you have to access them while the Session is still open

Comment: Ok, it's been a while since I had to worry about the Session (working in Play Framework atm (-:)